# power bi filter filter by columns

Tags: powerbi, transformation

I have got following Power BI table.

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4 
   A         1         11       abc
   B         2         abc12    132
   A         54        asd      ab12
   C         zza       e434     re43
   B         2df       43gf     sw3
```

I want to transform this table on the basis of 1st column (Column 1) as follows

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4 
   A         1         11       abc
             54        asd      ab12
   B         2         abc12    132
             2df       43gf     sw3
   C         zza       e434     re43
```

Can you please help me in this regard?
Thanks
Aria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Columns 1 and 2 on the Rows in a matrix visual and the others in the Values.

If you drill down, then you should get something like this:

[image: Reshaped]